# Difference between python3.7-dev and python3-dev header files

Tags: header-files, python-3.7

What is the difference between the header files of the python3-dev and python3.x-dev packages. Is it ok to replace with python3-dev a more specific version (e.x 3.7) ?

Comment: I have more general question. For slim Dockerfile builds, is there a difference between `python-dev` and `python3-dev`?

Comment: python-dev refers to python2.7 probably.

Comment: Yes, but `python-dev` works with `python3` as well... so generally its a question of what to choose? `python-dev`? `python3-dev`? `python3.7-dev`?